# Falla en remover dato en un BST Javascript

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo están?, ando aprendiendo JavaScript y quería tener armado un BST como referencia con la gran mayoría de los métodos los cuales se pueden aplicar en el mismo.

Realmente todos métodos se implementaron bien, el problema surgió cuando quise implementar el borrar datos, lo estuve mirando y controlando pero no deja de darme el error:

> cannot read property data of undefined

Si alguien podría darme una sugerencia estaría agradecido.

Desde ya muchas gracias, mi código es el siguiente:

```
MiniNodo() {
    if(!this.raiz) return null;
    let Node = this.raiz;
    while (Node.left) {
        Node = Node.left
    }
    return Node.data
}
ObtenerRaiz() {
    return this.raiz;
}
Borrar(data) {
    this.raiz = this.SuperBorrar(this.raiz, data);
}
SuperBorrar(Node, dato) { 
    if(Node === null) {
        return null;
    } 
    else if (dato < Node.data) {       
        Node.left = this.SuperBorrar(Node.left, dato); 
        return Node; 
    }  
    else if(dato > Node.data) { 
        Node.right = this.SuperBorrar(Node.right, dato); 
        return Node; 
    }  
    else {  
    if(Node.left === null && Node.right === null)  { 
        Node = null; 
        return Node; 
    }  
    if(Node.left === null) { 
        Node = Node.right; 
        return Node; 
    }  
    else if(Node.right === null) { 
        Node = Node.left; 
        return Node; 
    }  
    var aux = this.MiniNodo(Node.right); 
    Node.data = aux.data; 
  
    Node.right = this.SuperBorrar(Node.right, aux.data); 
    return Node; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si se presenta el error en la función súper borrado o en borrado, lo que veo con lo que tienes publicado es que al final de tu función *SupeBorrado*, creas un nodo auxiliar con la función *MiniNodo*, está función *MiniNodo* no retorna un nodo sino que retorna la data dentro del nodo más pequeño que hay en el árbol, luego tú usas la propiedad “*data*” del “*aux*” pero dentro del *aux* lo que hay es un número, por lo tanto no te debería funcionar, revisa si ese es el error.